# Inserting IP Address into an inet field in Postgres using PySpark

Tags: postgresql, pyspark

I'm trying to insert a PySpark dataframe into a Postgres table but the two IP address columns are causing an error on insert.  The two Postgres columns are defined as the type inet.

I'm unable to cast the columns in the PySpark dataframe as inet and the current column type of "character varying" is causing insertion errors like below:

`"ip_orig_h" is of type inet but expression is of type character varying`

What is the proper way to submit an IP address from a PySpark dataframe to Postgres?  Is it a matter of casting as a different type that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you run a native Postgresql insert query in PySpark?

Comment: Would that detract from the speed of Spark?  I'm still learning

Comment: No, using native queries is at least as fast, often faster.